# How to show UTC time in local timezone in Django view?

Tags: django, django-views, timezone, django-timezone

I use UTC in my Django app and I want to display the time for my local timezone; 'Europe/Stockholm'. I just can't get this simple thing to work so I must be doing something wrong. I just can't figure out what it is...

This is what I have in my settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

And this is how I get the date that is passed to my template:

```
my_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

And finally this is what i have in my template file:

```
{% load tz ‰}

{% timezone 'Europe/Stockholm' %}{{ my_time|time }}{% endtimezone %}
```

But whatever timezone I use in {% timezone ... %} the date always read the same 20:31, and the local time should in fact be 22:31.

Thankful for any help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `settings.py` change `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'` to `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Stockholm'`

You also need to replace utcnow() method with now()

```
my_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: I tried that too without success... The output did not change.

Comment: check the edited answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

The [normal way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) to use local times is to set `TIME_ZONE` or call `activate()`.

That said, you can use the `timezone` template tag if you want to. The problem is with [`utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow). As noted in the documentation, that returns a naive datetime, which means that it's not timezone-aware. Use Django's [`now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) instead; that will return a timezone-aware datetime that can be adjusted.